# Needing help on a python program. How to search and save IDs from a HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Currently I'm trying to write a program that will search for a tag and the characters in front of that tag (until a space or enter) on a html local file but i don't know how, I worte some code but it isn't working, it only lists all the text on the html instead of looking for the PA and the characters.

Here's my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

ecj_data = open('output.html', 'r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(ecj_data, 'lxml')
d = 'PA'
soup_strings = [ l for l in list(soup.strings) if l.strip() != '' ]
for s in soup_strings :
    print(s)
```

Comment: And where exactly should your program be "looking for the PA and the characters"?

Comment: sorry you're right, I pasted the wrong code file, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to search word including 'PA'? Please try below.

```
for i in soup.strings.split(' '):
    if 'PA' in i:
        print (i)
```

Comment: It returned an error "'generator' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: Since don't know what is in your soup.strings, please paste 'soup.strings' value.

Comment: I'm doing it with a test html but i can paste here, Ill print with gyazo:
https://gyazo.com/ae1e94f3b1ae990d67372d79a57987b3